# preg_match for sentences beginning with 'for the'

Tags: php, preg-match

Pretty simple but I cant get the exact syntax working.

I just want a true or false check to see if a string beings with 'for the' (case insensitive).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it's just that, then you could use plain text searching:

```
if (stripos("for the", $text) === 0) { // case-insensitive here
    // string starts with "for the"
}
```

Or,

```
if (substr($text, 0, 7) == "for the")
```

---

The comments below got me wondering about which is actually faster, so I wrote some benchmarking.

Here's the TLDR version:

- `strpos` is really fast if you're not working with large strings.
- `strncmp` is reliable and fast.
- `preg_match` is never a good option.

Here's the long version:

- Two different "haystacks":

  1. 10000 characters of [lipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/)
  2. 83 characters of lipsum.
- 5 different searching methods:

  1. [strpos](http://php.net/strpos):
     `return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0`
  2. [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)
     `return preg_match("/^$needle/", $haystack) === 1`
  3. [substr](http://php.net/substr)
     `return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle`
  4. [strncmp](http://php.net/strncmp)
     `return strncmp($needle, $haystack, strlen($needle)) === 0`
  5. Manual looping:

```
for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($needle); $i < $l; ++$i) {
    if ($needle{$i} !== $haystack{$i}) return false;
}
return true;
```

- 7 different "needles"

  - 3 matching (lengths: 83, 5 and 1 character)
  - 4 non-matching (lengths: 83, 82, 5 and 1 characters). The 82 char needle doesn't match at all, and the 83 character needles matches all but the last character.
- 100,000 iterations, per method per needle per haystack

Interesting points:

- The fastest individual test of all was `strpos` on the long, entirely non-matching needle against the short haystack.

  - In fact, out of the 14 tests run per method, `strpos` recorded the top 11 times.
- The slowest individual test was the manual method on the long needles, regardless of haystack size. Those four tests were 10-20 times slower than almost all the other tests.
- Though `strpos` had the best performance, it was weighed down by the long non-matching needles on the long haystack. They were 5-10 times slower than most tests.
- `strncmp` was fast *and* the most consistent.
- `preg_match` was consistently about 2 times slower than the other functions

```
Haystack: 83 characters
              ______________________________________________________________
 ____________|__________ non-matching ___________|_______  matching ________|
| function   |   1    |   5    |   82   |   83   |   1    |   5    |   83   |
|------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
| manual     | 0.2291 | 0.2222 | 0.2266 | 4.1523 | 0.2337 | 0.4263 | 4.1972 |
| preg_match | 0.3622 | 0.3792 | 0.4098 | 0.4656 | 0.3642 | 0.3694 | 0.4658 |
| strncmp    | 0.1860 | 0.1918 | 0.1881 | 0.1981 | 0.1841 | 0.1857 | 0.1980 |
| strpos     | 0.1596 | 0.1633 | 0.1537 | 0.1560 | 0.1571 | 0.1589 | 0.1681 |
| substr     | 0.2052 | 0.2066 | 0.2009 | 0.2166 | 0.2061 | 0.2017 | 0.2236 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Haystack: 10000 characters
              ______________________________________________________________ 
 ____________|__________ non-matching ___________|_______  matching ________|
| function   |   1    |   5    |   82   |   83   |   1    |   5    |   83   |
|------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
| manual     | 0.2275 | 0.2249 | 0.2278 | 4.1507 | 0.2315 | 0.4233 | 4.1834 |
| preg_match | 0.3597 | 0.3628 | 0.4147 | 0.4654 | 0.3662 | 0.3679 | 0.4684 |
| strncmp    | 0.1886 | 0.1914 | 0.1835 | 0.2014 | 0.1851 | 0.1854 | 0.1989 |
| strpos     | 0.1605 | 2.1877 | 2.3737 | 0.5933 | 0.1575 | 0.1597 | 0.1667 |
| substr     | 0.2073 | 0.2085 | 0.2017 | 0.2152 | 0.2036 | 0.2090 | 0.2183 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: +1, regular expressions are generally more resource intensive than strpos() and related.

Comment: This was my first instinct as well, but it's pretty inefficient for large strings. Even if $text doesn't start with "for the" it'll keep searching the rest of the string, which could be thousands of bytes.

Comment: @Jordan, isn't the same true of regexes?

Comment: +1 for reminding that, in simple cases, it's preferable to use the str_ functions rather than the preg_ ones. It's simpler, more readable, and more efficient.

Comment: @Jordan: substr won't do that.

Comment: @Andy E: It might not be true of regexes if the pattern is anchored to the beginning of the string with  with ^ - you would hope it would give up more quickly than stripos

Comment: +1 for a really well thought out answer. It's interesting to see that the most consistent is `preg_match`, there must be a tipping point in terms of haystack size / matching needles that `preg_match` would be the preferred option.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `^` to signify the beginning of a string:

```
$string_one = "For the love of Mike";
$string_two = "for the amazing reason.";

$match = preg_match("/^for the/i", $string_one); // Outputs 1
$match = preg_match("/^for the/i", $string_two); // Outputs 1
```

The `/i` is the part that makes the search case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if(preg_match("/^for the/", $yourString))
{
    return true;
}                   
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Note the code of `^`, matches the start of a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you had [read the first example in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you would have seen the answer.

```
if ( preg_match('/^for the/i', $sentence) )
{
    // a match was found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex is `/^for the/i`